# Add Underline at HyperlinkButton XAML - UAP Win10

Tags: xaml, hyperlink, windows-10

I need your help.

I add a hyperlinkbutton and this have an underline above the text but, when I add one textblock with two Run's, the underline disappear.

If I remove the aplicated styles, the problem is the same.
(TextDecorations/TextDecoration not work for me)

I don't know the problem :/

Somebody help me?

Code:

```
            <HyperlinkButton x:Name="HyperLinkManager" Margin="40,0,0,24" Style="{StaticResource StyleHyperlinkButton}" Template="{StaticResource HyperlinkButtonControlTemplate}">
                <HyperlinkButton.Content>
                        <TextBlock >
                            <Run Text="Example 0"/>
                            <Run Text="Example 1" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                </HyperlinkButton.Content>
            </HyperlinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HyperlinkButton only underlines raw text on its own. If you set the content to something more complex (like a Button or an Image or a TextBlock) then you're in charge of your own underlining.

You can add an <[Underline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.underline.aspx)> element to your TextBlock inlines:

```
<HyperlinkButton.Content>
    <TextBlock >
        <Underline>
            <Run Text="Example 0"/>
            <Run Text="Example 1" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        </Underline>
    </TextBlock>
</HyperlinkButton.Content>
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. Good answer. Very useful. Work. Thanks